# How can External Assemblies deal with SSRS variables?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to create an External Assembly and reference it inside my SSRS reports, so that I avoid repeating functions like this on every report I create:

```
Public Function UserName()
Try
Return Report.User!UserID
Catch
Return "System"
End Try
End Function
```

However, "Report.User!ID" won't be available inside my external assembly.

I'm trying to implement item 7 from: http://www.ssw.com.au/Ssw/Standards/Rules/RulesToBetterSQLReportingServices.aspx#userExperience

Comment: For simple logic like your sample, you could create a report variable (called `UserName` for example) and use it in your report like this: `=Variables!UserName.Value`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. How can I catch exceptions inside a Variable Value Expression? And how it could avoid me repeating/duplicating code for every report?

Comment: Are you willing to create data-driven subscriptions?

Comment: No, at least no yet.

Comment: Ok, then you could use directly "User!UserID" in the variable expression. The advantage of using a variable would be that it will be easier to update if the logic to get the username changes. Now if you want to avoid copy/pasting everything you want to reuse, you could create a report template and use that template for future reports. Just note that any future modification will have to be done to every report created.

Comment: Thanks for helping. What about creating a Report Processing Extension? I don't know much about it,